# Country based redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to restrict which country can access my webpage, but I can't get it to work.

I tried following [this guide](http://www.trafficplusconversion.com/251/redirect-based-on-country/).

It gives me lots of error when it is hosted on my localhost (XAMPP).  Check error from screenshot:

[image: My Image]

And if it is uploaded to some free hosting it gives me an infinite "LOOP" when accessing `domain.com/index.php` or `domain.com/redirect.php`.

But on [this webpage](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php) it works, and shows my details perfectly
(country, country code, latitude, longitude etc.)

I've pasted those two files on the same folder and trying it to access on my computer which is:

http://localhost/geoplugin.class/index.php

Comment: Localhost cannot be used to test these redirections in primary. At the hosting, are you redirecting to the same page, or a page which also included this redirection code?

Comment: Post your code, please!

Comment: My codes are which i did copy the tutorials from here:

tutorial link kar.in/zu
so i have 3 files:

geoplugin.class.php
index.php
&
redirect.php

So if it does not work on localhost. 
Everytime I uploaded it on my free hosting it does loop and loop.. 

could u guys add me on skype though?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it ..Is to use .htaccess

Here is website that will generate htaccess country block codes:

http://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx